# Error in AWS Elasticbeanstalk deployment flask app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Flask app using EB CLI having requirements.txt file.

```
eb init
eb open flask-env
```

Application is properly uploaded on the server, but it's health status says Severe.
 I am getting the following errors.

- In the dashboard

```
Command failed on all instances.
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances

Application deployment failed at 2020-07-01T03:49:21Z with exit status 1 and error: Engine execution has encountered an error.
Instance ELB health state has been "OutOfService" for 14 minutes: Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively.
```

- In the logs

```
[ERROR] Creating a Pipfile for this projectâ€¦
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfileâ€¦
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c python3 -m pipenv install -r requirements.txt --skip-lock failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Creating a Pipfile for this projectâ€¦
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfileâ€¦
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I also deployed multiple applications but they are also giving the same error

Comment: What's your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: It contains all the required name packages for deployment.

Comment: The error message indicates that there are some strange characters there. Have you inspected that?

Comment: I used ```pip freeze > requirements.txt``` command to create the file.

Comment: For some reason you get `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0` error. Seems like its something wrong with your file.

Comment: Here is the content of my requirements.txt file
```click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
six==1.15.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your requirement.txt file and regenerate but this time save your requirement.txt file as a UTF-8 file.

Here are some helpful links:

[requirement.txt file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format)

[Deploy flask application to elastic beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html)